# Show Page Not Working For Accepts_Nested_Attributes_For

Tags: ruby-on-rails, accepts-nested-attributes

Trying learn accepts_nested_attributes_for in basic has_many and belongs_to association.

Problem is that it's not working in the show page ...

The error I get is:

```
NoMethodError in Authors#show   

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

in relation to this line: `<%= @book.each do |b| %>`

Basic setup is:

**Author**

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :books

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
end
```

**Book**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :author
end
```

**Author _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: author, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if author.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(author.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this author from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% author.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :author_name %>
  </div>

  <h3>Book </h3>
  <%= form.fields_for :books do |b| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= b.label :title %><br />
      <%= b.text_field :title %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Author's Controller**

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_author, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /authors
  # GET /authors.json
  def index
    @authors = Author.all
  end

  # GET /authors/1
  # GET /authors/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /authors/new
  def new
    @author = Author.new
    @book = @author.books.build
  end

  # GET /authors/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /authors
  # POST /authors.json
  def create
    @author = Author.new(author_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.save
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @author }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /authors/1
  # PATCH/PUT /authors/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.update(author_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @author }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /authors/1
  # DELETE /authors/1.json
  def destroy
    @author.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to authors_url, notice: 'Author was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_author
      @author = Author.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def author_params
      params.require(:author).permit(:name, books_attributes: [:id, :title])
    end
end
```

**Author's show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @author.name %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Book(s)</strong>
    <%= @book.each do |b| %>
        <%= "#{b.name}" %><br />
    <% end %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_author_path(@author) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', authors_path %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the **show** action put this

```
def show
 @books = @author.books
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<strong>Book(s)</strong>
<%= @books.each do |b| %>
    <%= b.title %><br />
<% end %>
```

in the **new** action remove the line

```
@book = @author.books.build
```